# Why are there specific prejudices or laws against pitbulls?

Tags: dogs, safety, legal

Why are there laws regulating the ownership of pitbulls but not, at least obviously, for other dogs?

For example: Some places will ban the ownership of pitbulls entirely, while others require them to wear muzzles while outside of their owner's property.

Comment: What laws are you talking about? I'm not aware of any laws that single out pitbulls from other vicious breeds. Also, it is not just these dogs, my insurance carrier has a long list of breeds they are weary of and recommend not renting homes to.

Comment: @JohnFx - Some jurisdictions have specific laws. For example, pit bulls are [illegal in Ontario](http://www.ontla.on.ca/web/bills/bills_detail.do?locale=en&BillID=323&ParlSessionID=38:1&isCurrent=false) there are also specific local bans in many [US States](http://www.dogsbite.org/legislating-dangerous-dogs-state-by-state.php) as well. The pit bull "breed" (not really a breed) is specifically singled out in a fair number of them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breed-specific_legislation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a combination of pitbulls being large, powerful dogs and being the fashionable choice of owners that are more interested in having a fierce animal under their control than having a balanced and happy dog.  So the normal risks of a big dog are increased by neglect and poor owners.

So while there are plenty of well raised pitbulls, of the dogs on the edge of attacking people more are pitbulls because their owners raise them that way.

When I was younger, German Shepherds and Dobermans were the fashion for the same reasons.

Comment: "having a fierce animal under their control"   Obviously they were not otherwise they would not have killed anyone.  Many outside the pitbull world have argued they are never safe adding to the hysteria

Comment: Responsible pitbull owners want a happy and content animal. Those who want danger are likely to find it when they don't expect it.

Comment: I think the conflict comes when people who do think they want a happy and content animal are inadvertently grooming one to be a pit bull of the wrong variety.   Thats the rub.  The same kind of blindness that shades the faults of children from their parents also applies to pets.

Comment: I don't agree that it is inadvertent on the owner's part.

Comment: It's all about what's in your heart, yo

Comment: Good parents raise good kids/good owners raise good pets?